# Filling missing dates within group with duplicate date pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill missing dates by ID, however one of my indexed column has a duplicate date, so I tried this code but i keep getting this error *"cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"*

These are two codes I have tried:

FIRST:

```
udates=data['day'].unique()
filled_df = (data.set_index('day')
             .groupby('ID')
             .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(min(data.day),
                                                      max(data.day),
                                                      freq='D')))
             .drop('ID', axis=1)
             .reset_index('ID')
             .fillna(0))
filled_df
```

SECOND ONE:

```
users = pd.unique(data.ID)
data.day= pd.to_datetime(data.day)
dates = pd.date_range(min(data.day), max(data.day))
data.set_index('day', inplace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
for u in users:
    df[u] = data[data.ID==u].val

df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df.val.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.val = df.val.astype(int)
df
```

this is an extract of the input data:

| day | ID | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/26/2020 | AA | 100 |
| 01/28/2020 | AA | 200 |
| 01/26/2020 | BB | 100 |
| 01/27/2020 | BB | 100 |
| 01/29/2020 | BB | 40 |

This the output I want to get:

| day | ID | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/26/2020 | AA | 100 |
| 01/27/2020 | AA | 0 |
| 01/28/2020 | AA | 200 |
| 01/26/2020 | BB | 100 |
| 01/27/2020 | BB | 100 |
| 01/28/2020 | BB | 0 |
| 01/29/2020 | BB | 40 |

Thank you

EDIT

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB','BB'], 
                   'day': ['1/26/2020', '1/28/2020', '1/26/2020', '1/27/2020','1/29/2020'], 'val': [100, 200, 100, 100, 40]})
```

Comment: Can you include the sample data that would be used to create your desired output? See: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for tips

Comment: thanks, I edit the question

Comment: ``df.set_index('day').groupby("ID").apply(lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(d.index.min(),d.index.max(), freq='D')))`` works fine for your code. Kindly share an example data with duplicates *within* a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df.set_index("day") \
      .groupby("ID")["val"] \
      .resample("D") \
      .first() \
      .fillna(0) \
      .reset_index()

   ID        day    val
0  AA 2020-01-26  100.0
1  AA 2020-01-27    0.0
2  AA 2020-01-28  200.0
3  BB 2020-01-26  100.0
4  BB 2020-01-27  100.0
5  BB 2020-01-28    0.0
6  BB 2020-01-29   40.0
```

Note: the function `first()` is useless. It's because [`Resampler.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.fillna.html) only works with the `method` keyword. You cannot pass a `value` unlike [`DataFrame.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).